# Programmatically Setting the Version of a Window's Service on the ProjectInstaller

Tags: c#

I have a Windows Service created in Visual Studio 2005 in C#.  I have a setup project and a ProjectInstaller class.  I also have code to programmatically get the version from the AssemblyFileVersionAttribute.

I need to figure out where I set the version that I've obtained (and where this code should go).  I tried placing it in the InitializeComponent method on ProjectInstaller.Designer.cs and then appending the version to serviceInstaller1.DisplayName and serviceInstaller1.ServiceName.  This didn't work and you're not supposed to modify the contents of this method.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than adding code to `InitializeComponent` I'd just add it to the `ProjectInstaller`'s constructor, after the call to `InitializeComponent`, I'm setting the `ServiceProcessInstaller1.Username` etc there without problems, but I think you need to get hold of the other installer to set the username so it might work if you do something like:

```
((ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller)ServiceProcessInstaller1.Parent.Installers[1]).DisplayName
```

Comment: Sorry for my delay in responding.  I was sidetracked on other projects.  I like the suggestion of putting it in the constructor after InitializeComponent.  However, an error is thrown stating that 'Installers' is a property and it's used like a method.  I tried to change this but couldn't come up with a viable solution.  I had also tried putting it in an override method for OnBeforeInstall, then setting the DisplayName and ServiceName properties for serviceInstaller1.  This didn't do anything, so I'm assuming that the serviceProcessInstaller needs to be set.

Comment: @user302004: Sorry about that, I think I mixed up C# and VB.Net a bit where it says (1) in my sample it should be [1] instead, I'll update my answer with that.

Comment: I will test it in the morning and let you know.  Thanks for the quick responses.

Comment: The syntax change compiled, but it didn't add the version when I deployed this on a test server.  In Add/Remove Programs and Services, the name of the service is still being displayed (without the version).

Comment: I noticed that the 'Installer' was zero-based and changed the one to a zero.  Now, on the install, an exception is being thrown stating that it's "unable to create an instance of serviceName.ProjectInstaller installer type.  Unable to cast object of type System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller to System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller.

Comment: @user302004: Yes, there's different kinds of installers in that collection. The second one in my install seemed the one most likely to work, but apparently it didn't. Sorry, can't think of anything else to do then.

Comment: @ho1:  Your code did work!  I tried overriding the Install method and ended up installing a second service.  This is where I noticed that my "version retrieval" code wasn't working.  I hard coded the version and your code successfully installed the new service and display names.  So, thanks a lot and I'll be "accepting your answer".

Comment: @user302004: Great, good to know in case I have to do that myself (I've done similar things but not exactly this).